# Acumatica Exception when I tried to Deploy New Application Instance

Tags: acumatica

I've got an exception when I tried to "Deploy New Application Instance" on Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard. Could anyone help me?

This is my screenshot:

[image]

This is Details for screenshot:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.

   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
   at ConfigCore.RemoteResourceLocator.OpenSubKeyLocalMachine(String strSubKey, Boolean rw)
   at ConfigCore.IISInstalled.GetSitesList()
   at ERPConfig.MainERP.FillInfo(String siteName)
   at ERPConfig.MainERP.SitePanel_VisibleChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at ConfigCore.BaseMain.NextNewInstance()
   at ConfigCore.BaseMain.Next()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.127.1 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
AcumaticaConfig
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.30.1138
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Acumatica%20ERP/Data/AcumaticaConfig.exe
----------------------------------------
ConfigCore
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.30.1138
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Acumatica%20ERP/Data/ConfigCore.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1075.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1068.2 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
PX.Config.Common
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.30.1138
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Acumatica%20ERP/Data/PX.Config.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
PX.BulkInsert
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.30.1138
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Acumatica%20ERP/Data/PX.BulkInsert.DLL
----------------------------------------
PX.DbServices
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.30.1138
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Acumatica%20ERP/Data/PX.DbServices.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Web.Administration
    Assembly Version: 7.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.10240.16384
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Web.Administration/7.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
PX.WebConfig
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.30.1138
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Acumatica%20ERP/Data/PX.WebConfig.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Design
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Design/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Design.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.1064.2 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.127.1 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.6.79.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Answer (score 2):

The installation is failing when trying to retrieve the list of sites configured on your local IIS instance. Please open IIS Manager and review the list of applications and sites to ensure that they all point to valid paths.